# Django show Field Based on ChoiceField Selection

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, templates

I've been having difficulty finding out how to create a text field in django that is dependent on the selection of another field in the form. It is only desired to show this field when the selection is set to, in this case "Purchase".

Right now I'm running into an issue where it is not updating based on the drop down selection, but only after I hit a button to "submit" the form. Is there some way to acquire the current selected value, or to manually trigger the clean/submit functionality?

```
{% if field != form.purchase_order %}
    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
{% endif %}
{% if field == form.purchase_order and form.purpose.data == 'PURCHASE' %}
    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
{% endif %}
```

[image]

Comment: i think you can't do that with `server rendering`, how about making use of jquery to listen to the input field `onchange` event?

Comment: You can't do this with just Django out of the box. You will need to handle it with javascript in your page.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up "brute forcing a solution" by editing forms.py and was wondering if you had a better solution?  

    My Solution:  

`purpose = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PURPOSE_CHOICES, widget = forms.Select(attrs={
'onchange': document.getElementById('purchase-order-id').setAttribute('style', (value=='PURCHASE') ? 'display:inherit' : 'display:none');
}))`

Comment: In general, it is best to keep your frontend on the frontend and the backend on the backend.  You can place this javascript code in a script tag or separate file (it would work the exact same way).  The other small benefit this would give is that the code you wrote is an inline javascript attribute, which is generally frowned upon (because javascript belongs in javascript and html belongs in html).