# Enable/Disable Django form fields based on ChoiceField selection?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a ChoiceField with 2 options and another CharField for key. I need the key field to only be editable or visible when the ChoiceField is set to private. My form in forms.py looks like this:

```
class CBNewForm(forms.Form):
CHOICES = (('public', 'Public',), ('private', 'Private',))
title = forms.CharField()
category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x,x) for x in CBData.getAllcategory()])
visibility = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES)
key = forms.CharField(required=False)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CBNewForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.initial['visibility'] = 'public'
```

So I need the 'key' to only be visible/editable if the visibility = 'private'.

I've looked at the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622176/django-show-field-based-on-choicefield-selection) and they suggest that this needs to be done in javascript so I'm hoping someone can show me how to add javascript to my .html files and excatly what i'd need.

My html file is very simple:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<h1>New Page</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}{{ form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-info ml-2" type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Rendered html:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">


        <a class="navbar-brand dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="mainMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false">CorkBoard</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" aria-labelledby="mainMenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Home</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/corkboards/dashboard/">Dashboard</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/corkboards/new/">New CorkBoard</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/corkboards/stats/">CorkBoard Stats</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/corkboards/pin/4/">Pin Detail 4 test</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/corkboards/detail/3/">CB Detail 3 test</a>
        </div>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
                aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false">abcd</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="userMenu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/password_change/">Change Password</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/logout/">Log Out</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

    <h1>New corkboard</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="I4sPqg8hnl7EfXgLAv0Mj0wPXtcjk4roADGAjjHx06TeovySQ0ENCcXEcWieS6KM">

<div id="div_id_title" class="form-group"> <label for="id_title" class="col-form-label  requiredField">
                Title<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class=""> <input type="text" name="title" class="textinput textInput form-control" required id="id_title"> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_category" class="form-group"> <label for="id_category" class="col-form-label  requiredField">
                Category<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div 

    class=""> <select name="category" class="select form-control" id="id_category"> <option value="Education">Education</option> <option value="People">People</option> <option value="Sports">Sports</option> <option value="Other">Other</option> <option value="Architecture">Architecture</option> <option value="Travel">Travel</option> <option value="Pets">Pets</option> <option value="Food &amp; Drink">Food &amp; Drink</option> <option value="Home &amp; Garden">Home &amp; Garden</option> <option value="Photography">Photography</option> <option value="Technology">Technology</option> <option value="Art">Art</option>

    </select> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_visibility" class="form-group"> <label for="id_visibility_0" class="col-form-label  requiredField">
                    Visibility<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class=""> <div class="form-check"> <label for="id_id_visibility_0_1" class="form-check-label"> <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" checked="checked" name="visibility" id="id_id_visibility_0_1" value="public" >
            Public
        </label> </div> <div class="form-check"> <label for="id_id_visibility_0_2" class="form-check-label"> <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="visibility" id="id_id_visibility_0_2" value="private" >
            Private
        </label> </div> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_password" class="form-group"> <label for="password_text" class="col-form-label ">
                Password
            </label> <div class=""> <input type="text" name="password" id="password_text" class="textinput textInput form-control"> </div> </div>

        <button class="btn btn-info ml-2" type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('private_box').onchange = function () {
            document.getElementById('password_text').disabled = !this.checked;
        };
    </script>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML file?

Comment: @robotHamster HTML added to question.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear.. I mean the rendered http from your browser. Run your development server, go to the page, click `F12` on your keyboard, and include the html output. I apologize for not making that clear the first time...

Comment: @robotHamster sorry about that, added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your rendered html, I think adding this to the end of your html template (or in a `{% block page_js %}` ) should give you the desired behavior:

```
<script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { //function will wait for the page to fully load before executing

        $("input[type=radio][name=visibility]").change(function () { //specifying onchange function for input of type radio and name visibility
            console.log("Change!")
            if (this.value == "private") { //if the new value is private
                $("#password_text").prop('disabled', true);//would recommend readonly instead of disable for form integrity
                console.log("Disabling");


            }else{ //if the new value is anything else
                    $("#password_text").prop('disabled', false);
                    console.log("Enabling");
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The first script will include `jQuery`, which is a popular library that you can also download and use (I use the CDN from [here](https://code.jquery.com/) to include it in the example)

The second script is more-or-less explained in the comments!

Comment: Brilliant, this worked great. Thank you so much. If its not too much trouble, what's a good resource to pickup elementary javascript for django projects like what you posted above?

Comment: I personally only learned a very small amount of javascript on [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/). I would focus on syntax, if-else, variables, and some built in functions. The [document object docs on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) has done me well previously. Once you feel a little comfortable doing elementary stuff, tackle [this jQuery tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)

Comment: Please note that __you can__ just dive into jQuery, but having some javascript basics can really come in handy and help you write better code overall @doddy 

I hope this helps!