# Disable option charField choices depending on another atribute (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So, I have the following in my models.py:

```
UNITY_CHOICES = (
    ('g', 'Gram(s)'),
    ('kg', 'Kilogram(s)'),
    ('l', 'Liter(s)'),
    ('cl', 'Centiliter(s)'),
)
class Recipe_Ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)

    quantityUnit = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=UNITY_CHOICES,
        default=GRAM,
    )
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    articleNumber = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    costPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    costAmout = models.FloatField()
    costUnity = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=UNITY_CHOICES,
        default=GRAM,
    )
```

And I have a simple form to add this model to my database:

```
class Recipe_IngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe_Ingredient
        fields = ('quantity', 'quantityUnit', 'ingredient')
```

So I was wondering if there's a way of filtering the quantityUnit available choices depending on the ingredient chosen.
I'll try to make it clear by an example: Let's say I choose to add Potato and the costUnity for Potato is 'g', then I want to make 'kg' and 'g' the only choices for quantityUnit. Is that a good example? I can try to think of something better if it's not clear enough.
Anyway, is it possible to do such thing? Thanks.

UPDATE:
forms.py:

```
class Recipe_IngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe_Ingredient
        fields = ('quantity', 'quantityUnit', 'ingredient')
```

template:

```
{% extends 'recipe/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Add Ingredient to Recipe</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<h1>Add Ingredient to Recipe</h1>
<form method="POST" class="post-form"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="tXVR3NM1R4TBwOJArWWClL71r8S5C18gWKz9mKK42wlEamf6NcBjzrieF5dQBOaO">
    <p>
        <label for="id_quantity">Quantity:</label>
        <input type="number" name="quantity" required="" id="id_quantity" step="any">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="id_quantityUnit">QuantityUnit:</label>
        <select name="quantityUnit" id="id_quantityUnit">
            <option value="g" selected="">Gram(s)</option>
            <option value="kg">Kilogram(s)</option>
            <option value="l">Liter(s)</option>
            <option value="cl">Centiliter(s)</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="id_ingredient">Ingredient:</label> <select name="ingredient" required="" id="id_ingredient">
        <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
        <option value="1">Carrot</option>
        <option value="2">Potato</option>
        <option value="3">Water</option>
        <option value="4">Juice</option>

        </select>
    </p>
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, very possible with Javascrip/jQuery in your template. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359362/enable-disable-django-form-fields-based-on-choicefield-selection/53385233#53385233) an answer to a somewhat similar question. You would have to play around with your `option` elements

Comment: I don't think its possible unless you use any JQuery or other Javascripts to render them dynamically.

Comment: @robotHamster So I would have to place a script tag at the bottom of the template where my form is being called. But how would I be able to get selected ingredient and the costUnity attribute of this selected ingredient?

Comment: You can use jQuery AJAX calls to update the information from your database

Comment: @robotHamster I have added the script at the bottom and triggered on change of the select field, but I still don't know how I can get the attribute costUnity from the selected ingredient. Can you help me out? Maybe with a simple example?

Comment: to help you out with some jQuery, I would need to see your rendered HTML, please update your post to include it

Comment: @robotHamster Ok, I updated it with my form and template. I'm using Django Forms and when I inspect I see that the Ingredient select field gets an Id "id_ingredient" and the unity select "id_quantityUnit".

Comment: @robotHamster if you need to see my views.py handling the form, let me know as well.

Comment: @robotHamster, I just added the rendered html to it.

Comment: I got it working, will post my answer later when I'm home.